# Apps to interact with Android allowed?

Tags: discussion

Would it be on topic to ask for ways to use a desktop/laptop computer to edit the online information on an Android device that syncs across multiple Google accounts? Or would such a question be more suited for the Android SE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to get a better answer on the Android site. Depending on how it's worded, it might be on topic here, but it seems more appropriate for the site that's dedicated to Android stuff.